# Navigator push argument to the url in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I can push all the arguments to the pages that I stated. The problem is the id of the product is not passed to the url in the flutter web. When I click the button in the Favorites class, the url becomes http://localhost:5000/#/prod instead of http://localhost:5000/#/prod/rebEZ0Wswa5UXKfkKjSV (The last part of the url is productId)

```
const String HomeRoute = '/';
const String FavoritesRoute = '/favs';
const String ProductDetailRoute = '/prod';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          initialRoute: HomeRoute,

   routes: {
        HomeRoute: (context) => HomePage(),
        FavoritesRoute: (context) => Favorites(),
        ProductDetailRoute: (context) =>
            ProductDetails(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments),
      },
        );
      }
    }

class ProductDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final productDetailsName;
  final productDetailsImage;
  final productDetailsoldPrice;
  var productDetailsPrice;
  final productDetailsDesc;
  final productDetailsQty;
  final productId;
  final productTime;
  var productDetailsWinner;

  ProductDetails(this.productId,
      {this.productDetailsName,
      this.productDetailsImage,
      this.productDetailsoldPrice,
      this.productDetailsPrice,
      this.productDetailsDesc,
      this.productDetailsQty,
      this.productTime,
      this.productDetailsWinner, arguments});

class Favorites extends StatefulWidget {
...
...
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
             return Scaffold(
          body: Container(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
               
  Navigator.pushNamed(context,ProductDetailRoute,
                       arguments: ProductDetails(
                       snapshot.data[index]["productId"],
                       productDetailsName: snapshot.data[index]["name"],
                       productDetailsImage: snapshot.data[index]["image"],
                       productDetailsoldPrice: snapshot.data[index]["oldPrice"],
                       productDetailsPrice: snapshot.data[index]["price"],
                       productDetailsDesc: snapshot.data[index]["prodDesc"],    
                            ),
                          ),
        },
      ),
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using fluro package

Answer (score 0):

Navigator.pushNamed method is takes 2 mandatory arguments (BuildContext context, String routeName) and one optional arguments (Object? argument), in your code above:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,ProductDetailRoute,
                       arguments: ProductDetails(
                       snapshot.data[index]["productId"],
                       productDetailsName: snapshot.data[index]["name"],
                       productDetailsImage: snapshot.data[index]["image"],
                       productDetailsoldPrice: snapshot.data[index]["oldPrice"],
                       productDetailsPrice: snapshot.data[index]["price"],
                       productDetailsDesc: snapshot.data[index]["prodDesc"],    
                            ),
                          ),
        },
```

the route name would hold on this variable **ProductDetailRoute** try to make it a function that take product id and return it like this:

```
String _getProductDetailRouteName(String id){
    return '/prod/$id';
}
```

and assign it

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,_getProductDetailRouteName(id),
                       arguments: ProductDetails(
                       snapshot.data[index]["productId"],
                       productDetailsName: snapshot.data[index]["name"],
                       productDetailsImage: snapshot.data[index]["image"],
                       productDetailsoldPrice: snapshot.data[index]["oldPrice"],
                       productDetailsPrice: snapshot.data[index]["price"],
                       productDetailsDesc: snapshot.data[index]["prodDesc"],    
                            ),
                          ),
        },
```

Comment: Where exactly I need to define the _getProductDetailRouteName ? When I define it in Favorites class I got an error "Another exception was thrown: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/prod/Ceket", ProductDetails) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Comment: Are you are using onGenerateRoute on MaterialApp for defining routes?

Comment: No I didnt use it. I just used what I gave above

Comment: That's kinda tricky since the method you use above only accepts the predefined String for route name, try to use Navigator 2.0, it well suited for this case.